# Issue in Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to integrate the Sign-In functionality of Microsoft. I have registered my app in Azure Portal and My requirement is to give authority to any end-user (MS Account holder) to sign-in into my app and get the Access Token, so as per documentation i have set the client Id, Redirect URI, Tenant-ID to "Common", but its not allowing the personal MS account holder to sign-IN. Its giving below error:

"You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."

Can anyone help into this?

Answer (score 0):

You should register the Azure AD app as this type: **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts.**

[image]

If you want to modify the exist Azure AD app to make it support personal account login, you could modify the manifest file, setting `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` as the value for "signInAudience".

[image]

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute).

Comment: Hi Allen, I tried editing the file but giving the error as a invlid value

Comment: @TedS Please share a screenshot of how you edit it.

Comment: @TedS Any updates? You could edit your post to add a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you Allen for the response,I have created the new app with above required Sign-In audience setting and now i am able to sign-in but in response i am not receiving the Access Token or Id token in return. I am using OpenIdConnect code flow for this

Comment: I Am developing the Web API project and have integrated the MSGraph APIs but need to Sign-in to my Azure app using any MS account and get token to access the MSGraph API, but in this process i am receiving any code  or token in return , could you please assist or suggest is there any other code flow to integrate this functionality into Web API

Comment: @TedS You are trying to access Microsoft Graph from your Web API? See OBO flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow. The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain.

Comment: Hi Allen, Yes I am developing the API based application, and identifying how the personal MS account registration and sign-In/Sign-Out will take place into Azure AD using Angular UI + Backend API.

Comment: Hi Nishant, I have integrated the On behalf User flow for my project requirement and its working as expected. However can you suggest the best possible solution for accessing the multiple user's email account and fetching the Realtime Inbox and Saving to DB on basis of Authorization token of every user which expires every hour in API based application

Comment: @TedS Thank You for the response. Please allow me some time to investigate what would be the best approach in your scenario. I will update here when I have some information.

Comment: @Nishant Sure will wait for the solution